# Javascript to click a button if screensize is mobile?

Tags: javascript

I have a calendar displayed on a page that shows the "calendar" view by default, which, does not display well on mobile. The calendar has a button to change to a "list" view.

I am trying to use javascript to click that button if the screen size is less than 767px. The code below is not working. Any help?

Thanks!

```
<script>
function viewForm(){
  if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    function buttonclick(){
    var pagebutton= document.getElementsByClassName("fc-listMonth-button");
    pagebutton.click();
    }
  }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', viewForm);
</script>
```

Comment: You're declaring a function that you're not calling. Add `buttonclick();` inside your if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to remove buttonclick function, because you didn't call it.

```
<script>
function viewForm(){
  if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    var pagebutton= document.getElementsByClassName("fc-listMonth-button");
    pagebutton.click();
  }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', viewForm);
</script>
```